# How to launch simple python script in ubuntu to test Qt application with qtwebdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I used this instruction to test QtCalculator using Selenium with qtwebdriver: https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Use-QtWebDriver-to-run-your-application   (Option 2: WebDriver creates the application)

I cloned example with Qt Calculator

```
 git clone -b add_app_example https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver.git
```

I rebuild Webdriver and rerun WebDriver

I wrote this simple script in python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

WebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.24.1:9517"), capabilities);

wd.get("qtwidget://MyWidgetClass");
System.out.println("Native page source:\n" + driver.getPageSource());
WebElement elt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//QTextEdit"));
```

But I got this error:

```
 File "testCalculator.py", line 6
    WebDriver driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.24.1:9517"), capabilities);
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why do I get this error ? I copied this script from article below, but I am not sure, Is this script correct ? Will something work (I mean -
testing QtCalculator) ?

Comment: You have to decide if you want to program Python or Java. Mixing both can’t possibly work.

Comment: @deets
I want to write test in Python, sorry, I really don't know python, that is why I am doing such a stupid mistakes. Could you help me, please, rewrite this code in python, so I will see how this works ?

Comment: @VFbvb may I know where you did see python example if you actually did? from what I can see https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Use-QtWebDriver-to-run-your-application refers to a java example. You cannot just convert it to python.

Comment: If you just want to use selenium webdriver in python and nothing else, I feel that way looking at your imports, you could refer to http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

You actually just imported 2 python modules.. but the bulk of your code is using Java syntax :)